# Lua variable doesn't write back to nginx variable

Tags: nginx, lua

Here is my understanding of nginx variable in lua script. If you have a nginx variable $ngVar with value of "something", the value of ngx.var.ngVar is also "something". If you change ngx.var.ngVar to "something else" in content_by_lua_block, $ngVar should be "something else" outside that block. But I found that's not true. $ngVar is still "something". I expect it to be "something else". Did I miss anything or my understanding is wrong?

```
location / {
  default_type text/html;
  set $ngCheckFailed true;

  content_by_lua_block {
    local file = io.popen("myshellscript.sh")
    local result = file:read("*a")
    ngx.say(result)
    succeeded, error_msg, retcode = file:close()

    if retcode == 0 then
      ngx.say('passed ')
      ngx.say(ngx.var.ngCheckFailed)
      ngx.var.ngCheckFailed = false
    else
      ngx.say('not passed ')
      ngx.say(ngx.var.ngCheckFailed)
      ngx.var.ngCheckFailed = true
    end
  }

    if ($ngCheckFailed = true) {
        return 403;
    }
}
```

I can guaranty retcode is 0 and ngx.var.ngCheckFailed is set to false. But I always get a 403.

Comment: Yes, you did missing something. Nginx config isn't an imperative programming language. Both `set` and `if` directives are being executed during the `NGX_HTTP_REWRITE_PHASE` while `content_by_lua_block` will be executed during the very later `NGX_HTTP_CONTENT_PHASE`. You should not consider nginx config file as a imperative programming language. See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#http_phases) first.

Comment: I'm a beginner. Nginx, Lua are not my field. Your link is definitely very helpful. Thanks.